# Lubuntu installation problem

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, lubuntu, uninstall

I installed lubuntu alongside with windows 7. I cleared some space for it in a separate partition and it automatically took tat space and installed. But the problem is that the lubuntu does not have wifi or anything. Maybe the installation is corrupt. So i was thinking of installing it again. But now it is recognizing the other lubuntu and the windows is not found. So this time i give install alongside , it shows be the other lubuntu. So now how to remove lubuntu fully so that i can install it again. Also now when i see in disk management in windows, i am able to see unnamed partitions, but the recovery partititon tat used to present is currently missing !!

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

This time don't select any pre-configured option.

1. Boot Lubuntu.
2. Select "Something Else".
3. Select the partition with ext4.
4. Format it.
5. Create a new ext4 partition and select the boot order as /
6. Now, selecting this partiton, just click next.

Hope this works for you.